# Twitter bootstrap hides horizontal scrolling

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I am using http://app.raw.densitydesign.org/#%2F angular application and have used twitter bootstrap for accordion. Now, the problem is that when I am adding ui-bootstrap library, it is hiding the default horizontal scrolling functionality. Without this, it works fine. So any suggestion, how can I make it working with this library.

--  using 0.11.2 ui-bootstrap

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can override that by using overflow-x. I couldn't see accordion on the link you gave but generally you can apply it by:

http://jsfiddle.net/882jof8L/

```
//CSS
#your-accordion .panel-body {
    overflow-x: scroll;
}

//HTML
<div class="panel-body">
    <table style="width: 1000px;">...</table>
</div>
```

Properties you can use with overflow-x:

```
overflow-x: visible|hidden|scroll|auto|initial|inherit;
```

In your case adding your style sheet after bootstrap might help:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="YOUR_PATH/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="YOUR_PATH/YOUR_STYLE_SHEET.css">
```

Styles are applied in the order they are read by the browser. This means styles appears at the top of a style sheet will be changed by the last one.

For example following style will result paragraph as black:

```
p { color: red; }
p { color: black; }
```

Or you can force browser to show scroll by using:

```
overflow-x: scroll !important;
```

What does !important do:

CSS rules that has the !important directive will always be applied no matter where that rule appears in the CSS document.

Comment: !important is one of those things that should be avoided as much as possible and only used when there really just isn't another choice. There's no need to apply !Important if your stylesheet is included after the Bootstrap one

Comment: Thanks, I tried this and now I can see the horizontal scrollbar but it is greyed out. I mean I can see it is there but I can't scroll it. It seems that bootstrap is conflicting with scrolling functionality.

Comment: @user3050590 It means you don't have any element overlays the accordion. I added a fiddle link.

Comment: @HugoYates You're right It's not a good idea to say like, It's good to use generally. It might create a chaos later. That's why I removed it. Thank you.

Comment: @TolgaMengu, much better :) +1 to you